# Installing JDK 8 and JRE 8 silently on a Windows machine through command line

Tags: java, windows, silent-installer

We want to update the JDK environment on multiple machines, all running windows but different versions (either XP or 7)

For that purpose, I'm now creating a script which will automatically run the correct installer (32/64 bit).
I tried running the installer with the following command:

`jdk-8u25-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature,PublicjreFeature"`

This works fine on a machine with no JDK/JRE 8 installed. However, I am running into a few issues:

- If JDK/JRE 8 is already installed, the installer UNINSTALLS both JDK & JRE instead of simply not doing anything (or re-installing)
- If a reboot is required it is forcefully performed automatically, and I need to avoid that as there are other actions I need to perform in the script after the installation completes.
- There is no VERBOSE mode / log file to indicate what the installer is actually doing

I have looked at these sources:

- [JDK Installation for Microsoft Windows - Installing the JDK Silently](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#CHDHHBDD)
- [Windows JRE Installer Options - Command-Line Installation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_installer_options.html#CJAJGEHA)

but they seem lacking and very confusing as to what will give me the wanted result.

Comment: What is about deploy it as/in a folder and adjust the environment variables ?

Comment: Is it safe to deploy Java that way on a Windows machine? Isn't the installer also setting different registry values that might be needed by some programs?

Comment: Depends on your use case. Do you use the Java Browser Plug-in ? You shouldn't and if mandatory this probably won't work. You are running .jar with double-click ? Propably this solution won't work too. I'm not shure what will happen, if you make a version *agnostic* initial installation (specify C:\java as installation folder) and simple copy over new versions into that folder.

Comment: Too many "ifs", I'd rather get the silent installer working properly. I really find it odd that it's so under-documented

Answer (score 10):

I would tackle JDK and JRE separately:

The **JDK** does not depend on registry entries or whatever else the installer exe does. So install the JDK - **without** Public JRE - on just **one** machine using

```
jdk-8u25-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature"
```

Then you can simply zip up the resulting installation, copy and unzip it to other machines of the same OS type.

The **JRE** installer (separate download from Oracle) can be run with options and config file as documented here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_installer_options.html

Assuming the config is in the same directory as the installer exe, the option `INSTALLCFG="%cd%\jre-install-options.cfg"` can be used. Otherwise, a full path is required to the config file (INSTALLCFG="c:\path\to\jre-install-options.cfg"). So, something like this (with log file and assuming the config file is in the same directory of the exe):

```
jre-8-windows-i586.exe INSTALLCFG="%cd%\jre-install-options.cfg" /s /L C:\TMP\jre-install.log
```

It seems that the following jre-install-options.txt might work for you:

```
INSTALL_SILENT=Enable
REBOOT=Disable
STATIC=Enable
```

The config file options are listed here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html

The meaning of the last line is explained here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_installer_options.html#static_installation

Comment: A relative path for INSTALLCFG did not work for me. See my [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/970540/cannot-install-java-silently) question

Comment: What will the installer do if Java is already installed? Will it uninstall Java and reinstall it or will it only uninstall? And in the latter case will it indicate what it did, preferably not through the log? Will reboot be actually required before Java is usable?

Comment: I know this is rather old post, but the config file has the [REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html#table_config_file_options) flag that will remove old versions of the JRE. Setting this to zero might give you what you need.

Comment: I know it's really old, but I need it now, do I need to copy the JDK also?

Answer (score 3):

It seems there are constant changes to the supported commandline options.  For the latest 8 Update 131, I had to abandon all msiexec style options because none of them worked.  I used the documentation for the java version I downloaded to construct switches to the installer.  As shown in answers above, the config file options can be passed to the installer on the commandline.  The final command that I used in Packer to install Java on a Win2016 Server ami was:

```
Start-Process 'C:\Windows\Temp\jre-8u131-windows-x64.exe' `
  -ArgumentList 'INSTALL_SILENT=Enable REBOOT=Disable SPONSORS=Disable' `
  -Wait -PassThru
```

This command also adds Java to the system path by default, however not in the one it installs.  Open a new powershell shell and it will be in the path for that shell (Inspect with `$env.path`)

Sources of truth:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_installer_options.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html#table_config_file_options

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue with /s option. I i found a jdk bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8033364. I seems they have removed support for help or s. Try /qn it worked for me

jdk-8u92-windows-x64.exe /qn

Comment: I think `/s`  just silences error messages. So, by removing `/s` you will actually see pop-ups when there's an error.

Comment: this hasnt done it for me, i still get the UI up when executing the above with the /qn switches.

Comment: This works for me (Used in MDT) jre-8u231-win-x64.exe INSTALL_SILENT=1 AUTO_UPDATE=0 REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=1

Answer (score 0):

For JRE silent installation :

`start /wait msiexec /i "%~ java8.40x64.msi " JU=0 JAVAUPDATE=0 AUTOUPDATECHECK=0 RebootYesNo=No WEB_JAVA=1 /q`

You can see full post [here](http://www.get-itsolutions.com/java-silent-install-version-8-and-uninstall-older-version/).