# How to install java through command prompt

Tags: java, command-line

I want to install java through command prompt command lines. Will it could be possible?

Comment: your operating system..?

Comment: Windows 7, Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043588/installing-jdk-8-and-jre-8-silently-on-a-windows-machine-through-command-line

Comment: Well it is different for each java version I believe, but as I said in my answer, there is documentation about it on Oracle's website, [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml)

Comment: Thanks dan, your answer looks easier to implement

Comment: No worries. I'm glad I could help. When you get time to try it, if it does solve your problem, I would be grateful if you hit that tick :) Assuming it is right and no one gives you a better answer that is

Answer (score 1):

There is a page on their website, [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml), that explains how to do what you are after.

[image]